# Highcharts Dynamic using dictionary/list django dataset

Tags: highcharts

I'm new to highcharts and have an issue with creating a dynamic bar chart using the dictionary dataset. Could you please help/suggest with it.

Following is the dataset parsed to html:

```
data = {
'Queue1': [{'name': 'user1', 'tickets': 1}, {'name': 'user2', 'tickets': 1}], 'Queue2': [{'name': 'user3', 'tickets': 1}, {'name': 'user1', 'tickets': 1}], 'Queue3': [{'name': 'user1', 'tickets': 30}, {'name': 'user2', 'tickets': 37}], 'Queue4': [{'name': 'user4', 'tickets': 2}]
}
```

Would like to display as multiple bar charts with Queue's as category and list of users with tickets handled under each queue( dynamic dataset queried from sql)

Appreciate any help/suggestions.

Thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse your data to the format required by Highcharts, for example:

```
var key,
    series = [];

for (key in data) {
    series.push({
        name: key,
        data: []
    });
    data[key].forEach(function(el) {
        series[series.length - 1].data.push({
            name: el.name,
            y: el.tickets
        });
    });
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9asrxwej/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.data

Comment: Thankyou very much for the update and support. The code works, but my intended output was different as attached image.

Comment: Hi @Peram Srinivas, Ok, I have updated the code according to your requirements: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/j9cLtv3y/